# Editor Template Path Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have Created an Editor Template in this Path

> ~/Areas/Admin/View/Shared/EditorTemplates/Resource.cshtml

I have a controller in the same Area(Admin) which has two Methods i.e **Create** and **Edit**

In the **Create** And **Edit** View I have used Html.EditorFor() helper to call the template. However The **Create** View looks up the template at this Path

> ~/Areas/Admin/View/Shared/EditorTemplates/Resource.cshtml

which is fine.However The **Edit** View doesnot looks up at this very same path.
Instead it looks at this path

> ~View/Shared/EditorTemplates/Resource.cshtml

I need to make The **Edit** View look up to this path

> ~/Areas/Admin/View/Shared/EditorTemplates/Resource.cshtml

I have Tried Explicitly using this way `Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Resource,"~/Areas/Admin/View/Shared/EditorTemplates/Resource.cshtml")` but it doesnot work. It only uses this path

> ~View/Shared/EditorTemplates/Resource.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

You can tell explicitly what paths should be considered in the `global.asax.cs` file.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication  
{  
   protected void Application_Start()  
   {  
      ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();  
      ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine()  
      {  
         PartialViewLocationFormats = new[]  
         {  
            "~/View/Shared/EditorTemplates/{0}.cshtml",  
            "~/Areas/Admin/View/Shared/EditorTemplates/{0}.cshtml"  
         }  
      });  
   }  
}
```